# insert data from multiple rows to one row mysql

Tags: mysql, select, insert, group-concat

Ok here's the thing. I need to insert multiple rows in one column from table A to one row in table B using MySql

Here's an example of what im trying to achieve:

```
Table A
id | data
1  | name
2  | date
3  | more
```

From table A, i need to select all the rows in the data column and insert that data in one row of 'data' column of table B 
like this:

```
Table B 
id | data
1  | name, date, more
```

Here is my current code, however it isn't working and shows me an error `subquery returns more than one row`

```
INSERT INTO B (data) values (SELECT data from A)
```

Is there any way i can do this? Please excuse as i am a newbie :P

Thanks in advance!

Comment: oh that's "INSERT INTO B(data) VALUES (SELECT DATA FROM A)"

Answer (score 1):

Use [**GROUP_CONCAT**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) function

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO B (data) 
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(data) FROM A;
```

Comment: Oh that's great thanks!
Just one more thing, what if I have to insert data from selected rows of table A?
Eg I want the values of the data column of rows with id=1 or id=2 from A to B?
thanks in advance!

Comment: Oh it is a part of a problem i have been given by my IT professor to solve.

Comment: @user1987363: use a `WHERE` condition. e.g. `... FROM A WHERE A.id IN (1,2)`

Comment: @user1987363 Don't forgot to accept any of  the answer from all answers whichever you find works for you